# What's the difference between 'have become p.p.' and 'have been p.p.'?

Tags: usage

I think the two are interchangeable, but I am not sure.

> Given that the Internet ***has become integrated*** in everyday lives and the communication of social support is an important part of
> interpersonal interaction, it is not 1 surprising that much support is
> provided and received online.

Comment: “has become integrated” suggests that the integration happened gradually; “has been integrated” suggests that there was a discrete moment of transition, and implies more intention.  I cannot clearly say why.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't interchangeable, as they both refer to a different point in which an event occurred.

"Has become" indicates that something was one way in the past but is now different in the present. "Have been" means that something was one way and still is today.

For example:

"I didn't use to eat burgers and fries, but since I started working, they **have become** breakfast lunch and dinner for me."

And

"We **have been** living in the same house for 10 years."

Comment: What about: "I hated Sam but since our collective effort to address the students' issues we have been good friends."

Comment: @Man_From_India In that sentence I'd use “we have become good friends.”

Comment: @AntonSherwood I am fully aware of the fact you talked about in your first comment under the question. Yes it's trur. And in my sentence it happens over a period of time but my point is when that semantics is not that important, when only the end result is what matters and when we have no syntactic obligation, then it is okay to write my sentence, I think. See the sentence below: "Though the switch to mobile **has been** an interesting transformation among innovators, everybody thinks the next mobile app they are building is going to be a huge success."

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two different structures here.

In *"...the Internet has become integrated in everyday lives..."*:

**subject + [present perfect (active) with "become"] + adjective + adverbial**

- the **voice** is active (the subject ("the Internet") does the verb ("become")
- the **main verb and past participle** is "become"
- "integrated" is an **adjective** describing "the Internet"

In *"... the Internet has been integrated in everyday lives..."*:

**subject + [present perfect passive with "integrate"] + adverbial**

- the **voice** is passive (the subject does NOT do the verb),
- "been" is both **the past participle that combines with "has" to form present perfect"** and **the auxiliary verb "be" that forms the passive voice with "integrated"**
- "integrated" is the **main verb and past participle that combines with "been" to form the passive voice**

Comment: I mostly agree with you, but several details are garbled, especially in the second half. The **voice** is passive, not active: that's the point. _Been_ is not "the past participle of 'have'", it is the p.p. of _be_, used to form a perfect with "have". _Integrated_ is not "the past participle of "been", it is the p.p. of _integrate_, used to form a passive with "be". And the adverbial phrase has the same resultativ e role in both  cases.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks. Fixed... one hopes